# Creating Universal Search with Winform and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, sql-server-2012-express

I need to create a universal search in a WinForms app that can search across multiple tables for certain columns and give results in categorized format.

So if I type "James", I would get:

```
- Clients  
James Taylor  
James Brown  
-Suppliers  
Jammie James  

- Invoices 
Nro 11425 James
```

The dashed titles would be category or in this case table.

A theoretical or actual example will go a long way!

Comment: What are the particular problems that you have?

Comment: You can easily do this in Entity Framework by having an `Expression<Func<TEntity,string,bool>>` used as a search criteria for each entity type. I guess other `IQueryable<T>` ORMs `could` support that too.

Comment: I dont hace a specific question. Its a problem im going to tackle and wanted to get and idea of the best way to aproach it. Highcore thanks ill check it out